# Python, using threading with multiprocessing

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multiprocessing

Can someone explain why threading don't work in multiprocessing.Process.

I've attached some example to explain my problem.

I have a process that executed every second and write to file. When I run it from shell, it works as expected.

**stat_collect.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from threading import Timer
from os import path
from datetime import datetime

STAT_DATETIME_FMT = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'


def collect_statistics():
    my_file = 'test.file'
    if not path.exists(my_file):
        with open(my_file, 'w') as fp:
            fp.write(datetime.now().strftime(STAT_DATETIME_FMT) + '\n')
    else:
        with open(my_file, 'a') as fp:
            fp.write(datetime.now().strftime(STAT_DATETIME_FMT) + '\n')

    Timer(1, collect_statistics).start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    collect_statistics()
```

When I try to run it from other script (to work in background):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from multiprocessing import Process
from stat_collect import collect_statistics  # logger sc

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # This don't work
    p = Process(target=collect_statistics)
    p.start()

    while True:
        pass
```

Method collect_statistics executed only once, but if I use Thread(target=collect_statistics).start() it works as if I run it from shell. Why this is happen?

Answer (score 1):

Here is what is going on:

1. You start your process
2. `collect_statistics` runs
3. Timer is started
4. now the function called in the process(`collect_statistics`) is finished, so the process
   quit, killing the timer in the same time.

Here is how to fix it :

**stat_collect.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from threading import Timer
from os import path
from datetime import datetime
import time

STAT_DATETIME_FMT = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'


def collect_statistics():
    while True:
        my_file = 'test.file'
        if not path.exists(my_file):
            with open(my_file, 'w') as fp:
                fp.write(datetime.now().strftime(STAT_DATETIME_FMT) + '\n')
        else:
            with open(my_file, 'a') as fp:
                fp.write(datetime.now().strftime(STAT_DATETIME_FMT) + '\n')

        time.sleep(1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    collect_statistics()
```

And for the calling script :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from multiprocessing import Process
from stat_collect import collect_statistics  # logger sc

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # This don't work
    p = Process(target=collect_statistics)
    p.start()
    p.join() # wait until process is over, e.g forever
```

`p.join()` is just here to replace you infinite while loop, which is taking a lot of ressource for nothing.

Comment: So, calling Process is not the same as run stat_collect.py from command line? And why Timer is killing when running from Process and not killing when run script from command line?

Comment: You should look into python's [GIL](http://www.dabeaz.com/python/UnderstandingGIL.pdf). Basically in Python, 2 processes don't communicate with each other at all. Running from command line runs your code in a single process, and all variables (an `Timer`) are "shared". Running inside another process creates a parent process (the calling script), and a child process (created with `p=Process(...)`). The parent process doesn't communicate to the child, and has no idea that another Thread has been launched.